# make a copy of VM to other VM's in azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I want to deploy the basic VM I have created - meaning create more VM instances with the exact VM in azure.

Is there a tool that does that ?

Comment: Do you want to migrate your local VM to Azure? What is your VM OS type, Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **VMM Console**, to do that.

See link below I hope this could help you.

I believe this link could help you out:
[How to Copy an Existing Virtual Machine to Windows Azure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj605418%28v=sc.12%29.aspx)

Regards

Daniel